# Replace part of a string between hyphen and dot in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I would need to replace part of a string between two characters, the last hyphen and the last dot, in php. Any ideas?

```
$string = 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/2b146fdab6c33eb5ca12efe61424427b-1000x750.jpg'
```

The numbers can vary, 1000x750 is only an example.

```
$newstring = 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/2b146fdab6c33eb5ca12efe61424427b-600x400.jpg'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research?

Comment: I did manage to add the new string on a string without the hyphen like
 `$first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0]; 
$first_img = substr($first_img, 0, -4) .'-600x450'. substr($first_img, -4);`

Comment: Then show your effort in your question and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Check out the regex functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this script helpful:

```
// The string you want to replace between the two characters
$replacewith = "600x400";

// The example string you provided
$string = $newstring = 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/2b146fdab6c33eb5ca12efe61424427b-1000x750.jpg';

// Determine the start/end position of the last hyphen and period characters
$start = strrpos($string, "-");
$end = strrpos($string, ".");

// If both the hyphen and character are found, then do the replacement
if ($start && $end) {

    $newstring = substr($string, 0, $start+1) . $replacewith . substr($string, $end);

}

echo $newstring;

// Outputs http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/2b146fdab6c33eb5ca12efe61424427b-600x400.jpg
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Great answer, especially helpful with your comments explaining.Thank you!